# Put links and text on same line popup window

Tags: html, css

I have a popup window that should have a header, a save button, and a close button.

This code

```
<div>
    <a href="#close">Cancel</a>
    <a href="" class="spacer">............</a>
    <a href="#">Deselect your free blocks</a>
    <a href="" class="spacer">............</a>
    <a href="#close">Save</a>
</div>
```

does this:
[image: does this]

This code

```
<div>
    <a href="#close">Cancel</a>
    <a href="" class="spacer">............</a>
    <p >Deselect your free blocks</p>
    <a href="" class="spacer">............</a>
    <a href="#close">Save</a>
</div>
```

does this:
[image: does this]

(The class 'spacer' just sets opacity to 0)

Any idea how I can have something that's not a link there and still have it fit on one line?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the markup?

Comment: @ManojKumar This is just a small personal project, so I'm open to anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the flexbox layout for the div and use [`justify-content: space-around`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) for equally laying out space around the elements instead of the default no spacing behavior.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* CSS Reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#close">Cancel</a>
  <a href="" class="spacer">............</a>
  <p>Deselect your free blocks</p>
  <a href="" class="spacer">............</a>
  <a href="#close">Save</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change < p > to < span >. the (i think) sole reason of the existence of < p > is to put line breaks.